# Spring Data & MongoDB - UnsupportedOperationException on deleteBy

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm stucked on this problem with Spring Data and MongoDB.
I'm using MongoDB 3.x, Spring data 1.7 (I also tried with 1.8) and Java MongoDB Driver 3.0.1 .

When I try to delete a product form my DB it actually works fine but I got this:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot get n property for an unacknowledged write
    at com.mongodb.WriteResult.throwIfUnacknowledged(WriteResult.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.WriteResult.getN(WriteResult.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$DeleteExecution.deleteAndConvertResult(AbstractMongoQuery.java:425)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$DeleteExecution.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:415)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.deleteByProductIdAndActorId(Unknown Source)
    at social.picnik.marketplace.service.product.manager.ProductActionManagerImpl.unSaveProduct(ProductActionManagerImpl.java:134)
    at social.picnik.api.marketplace.controller.CustomerController.deleteProductsSaved(CustomerController.java:1865)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at social.picnik.api.marketplace.utils.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is happend when my method execute this line of my code (we're using Spring data MongoDB Repositories):

```
this.productSavedRepo.deleteByProductIdAndActorId(product.getId(), customer.getId());
```

My configuration into pom.xml is:

```
    <name>backend-services</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.mongodb.version>1.7.0.RELEASE</spring.data.mongodb.version>
        <java.mongodb.driver.version>3.0.1</java.mongodb.driver.version>
        <spring.social.facebook.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring.social.facebook.version>
        <spring.social.security>1.1.0.RELEASE</spring.social.security>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mongodb java driver 2.x -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${java.mongodb.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.mongodb.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tecacet.math.fsm</groupId>
            <artifactId>fsm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-r8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
            <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.com.robust-it</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloning</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.slugify</groupId>
            <artifactId>slugify</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use Apache HttpClient as HTTP Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Social -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.security}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.facebook.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <profileId>local</profileId>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>local</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/properties</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <profileId>dev</profileId>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/properties</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>stage</id>
            <properties>
                <profileId>stage</profileId>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>staging</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/properties</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <profileId>production</profileId>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>production</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/properties</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshot</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>lib</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/resources/lib</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
        <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

My domain model is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("554a30a7fa4d0e68590d3362"),
    "_class" : "social.picnik.marketplace.service.product.model.ProductSaved",
    "product_id" : "5531351565887dfae1cbac17",
    "actor_id" : "54e8899ad4c61796733ae2cf",
    "action_date" : ISODate("2015-05-06T15:17:59.512Z")
}
```

This code has been worked since we upgraded MongoDB from 2.6 to 3.0 .

Have you ever had something like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your domain model look like? What does your configuration look like? What's the exception you get (incl. stack trace)?

Answer (score 3):

The exception you are getting

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot get n property for an unacknowledged write

means that you are performing a write in an [**`Unacknowledged`** mode](http://blog.mongodirector.com/understanding-durability-write-safety-in-mongodb/#highlighter_224076) (*"fire and forget"*), and after that you are probably trying to read the result of the operation, causing the exception.

The solution is to perform the write in an `Acknowledged` mode, the default one.

The reason you were not getting the exception in `2.x` and you are getting it now in `3.x` is because it has been introduced in [this commit of `3.x` drivers](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/commit/f664faa3627fa12fc3838b9fb0c9c29d39d01bef):

> For an unacknowledged write, DBCollection now returns, instead of null, a WriteResult that is configured to throw exceptions for all property accessors.
>
> This is closer to the behavior of 2.x, which also returns an instance, but only sometimes will throw exceptions from property accessors (based on whether
> any other threads have used the socket in the mean time).

Comment: Since we are using Spring Data Repository, we do not have the control of this, i mean how can i force 
"ProductSaved deleteByProductIdAndActorId(String productId, String actorId);" to perform a write in Acknowledged mode?

Comment: @StefanoSaitta - That's incorrect. You control the `WriteConcern` on the `Mongo` or `MongoClient` level.